# Ordering a list per character length?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like this (this is just a brief example):

```
list1 <- c("FA")
list2 <- c("FA", "EX", "FA")
list3 <- c("FA", "FA")
list <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

I need to reorder `list` so that the longest vector (i.e. `list2`) appears on top (i.e. as `[[1]]`) and shorter vectors appear in descending order, like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "FA" "EX" "FA"

[[2]]
[1] "FA" "FA"

[[3]]
[1] "FA"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements to get the length, then use the resulting vector to re-order the list.

```
o <- vapply(list, length, 1L)
list[order(o, decreasing = TRUE)]
# [[1]]
# [1] "FA" "EX" "FA"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "FA" "FA"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "FA"
```